# Does soliciting support for an Area 51 proposal count as 'spam'?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, area-51

I met [this "question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344948/proposal-for-maple-s-e-on-area-51) (10k+) on Stack Overflow Meta. I think it may be spam, because the asker wants to promote their Area 51 proposal (they are even promoting it in their username), but I'm not 100% sure.

Should I flag that question as spam or not?

Comment: I wouldn't flag it as spam, but it is certainly off topic, and should be closed

Comment: Anyway, it cannot be treated as spam. Because he don't get any benefit from that.

Comment: I agree with @psubsee2003 it is off topic. but not spam

Comment: You could have searched a little. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242586/permissible-for-display-name-to-advertise-another-se-site

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal all that does is justify your screen name. There is nothing about posting on meta to advertise your proposal

Comment: It's gone now so I don't know what it said, but if posting a question "to promote an Area 51 proposal" _were_ spam, wouldn't posting a question about it _that included a link to the question_ be in danger of being considered "spam at one remove", since I expect most people seeing your question would click through to the original?

Comment: @TripeHound [Link for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb254.png)

Comment: @psubsee2003: Sorry, I meant to address that to "MapleSE-Area51Proposal"

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal: Are you and "Canada - Area 51 Proposal" the same user? This all seems rather sketchy to me.

Comment: @FrankerZ DavidG did three comments above yours.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the purest sense of the word, a meta post asking users to support a new site proposal on Area 51 is probably spam since it is soliciting and advertising something. But because of the harsh penalties that come with having a post deleted for being spam, I wouldn't flag it as such when it is a single instance (and first offense).

Instead it should be closed for being off topic because we don't want users continually posting "questions" on meta asking people to support their proposals. So you should flag/vote to close it, and similar such questions as off-topic and select the following option:

> This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail. See also: What is "meta"? How does it work?

A comment on the post explaining that it is off topic to advertise the site in that manner would probably be appreciated, but isn't required.

Now, if the user is spamming the post across multiple SE sites, keeps reposting, and/or is a habitual offender everytime he/she proposes a new site, that does change the situation a little. I would still avoid the spam flag, but instead flag it with a custom flag and explain the situation to the moderators. Let them deal with the user.